# How to find each item in a column in a delimited list from a UserForm textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a UserForm with a textbox that the user will fill in with a list of names delimited by "; ". These names are found in Column D on my sheet. For each name, I'd like to copy and paste the whole row to another sheet and then delete the row in the original sheet. I am running into a couple of roadblocks that I haven't been able to solve.

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

Application.Volatile

Dim x As Integer
Dim PINamesArray As String
Dim size As Long
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindRow As Range

Set SearchRange = Range("D5", Range("D2000").End(xlUp))


PINamesArray = Split(Me.PINames, "; ")

size = UBound(PINamesArray) - LBound(PINamesArray) + 1

For x = 1 To size

Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find(x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

FindRow.Row
RTBM = FindRow.Row
RTBM.Copy
.Paste Worksheets("Dropped-NotSelected").Cells(ERow, 1)
RTBM.Delete Shift:xlShiftUp


End Sub
```

1. I want the Find function to look for the item in the delimited list that corresponds to that integer, not the integer itself.
2. I know that there are probably multiple aspects of this code that aren't right, but I'm having trouble finding good examples to base off of.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot - I had to change some variables around (and fix a lot of weird typos you had going on), but this worked in my testing:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Long, ERow As Long
Dim PINamesArray As Variant
Dim size As Long
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindRow As Long

Set SearchRange = Range("D5:D2000")
ERow = 1

PINamesArray = Split(Me.PINames, "; ")

size = UBound(PINamesArray) - LBound(PINamesArray) + 1

For x = 1 To size

    On Error Resume Next
    FindRow = SearchRange.Find(What:=PINamesArray(x)).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If FindRow <> 0 Then
        Rows(FindRow).Copy
        Worksheets("Dropped-NotSelected").Cells(ERow, 1).PasteSpecial
        ERow = ERow + 1
        Rows(FindRow).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Can you explain the rationale behind the two On Error lines?

The typos were just me being a novice. :)

Comment: I deactivated the On Error lines, and I'm getting a subscript error (9) on the line: `FindRow = SearchRange.Find(What:=PINamesArray(x)).Row`. Thoughts?

Comment: You have to leave the on error lines- they're in case the find returns no results.